# VPN: IPsec tunnel between Private IP ASA & Public IP ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, network

We have a user that moved recently to an incubator, in order to secure his traffic between his computer and the office we purchased an ASA 5505 to connect to his desktop, and hoped we could configure it to form a vpn tunnel to our ASA 5520 sitting in our office.
[image]

This is a basic diagram i have for you, is it possible to form this tunnel?
If so, what do i have to put in as crypto map peer? What should i put as route?
on both ends

I apologize if this is incomplete and vague question, i am ready to share as much information from my side if requested

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Configure client router to forward traffic from   Asa 5520 wan ip, ports IP 50 & UDP 500, to ASA 5505. Vpn configuration to be on ASA 5505, but peer IP to be used is Client router public IP. VPN will end up in ASA 5505 as the port forwarded.

Edit: Services/ports to forward : IKE (UDP 500) & ESP (IP 50)